# second try: Find the radius in dependency of a (the side length)

Tags: geometry

[image]I am really hopeless with this task. I have been trying nearly all day now.It´s about finding a description for the three radius in dependency of a. somethin like r=3a for example.. My friend said it works with a formula for radius inside a triangle. ANd I tried to solve with pythagoras which led to: r²= (a²)² -4a³r+6a²r² -4ar²-4ar³+2(r²)² +a² -2ar+r²+2r².
can anyone please very urgent help me? I need it for my exam...Thank you!

[image]

Comment: This picture is not clear, nor is what is being asked.

Comment: why is it not whats beeing asked? i try to upload a clearer version

Comment: I meant that I have no idea what you are asking us to do here.

Comment: its suppsed to find out r (radius) in relation to a (the length of the side of the square). something like r= g*a + k+a

Comment: There is no relationship between the radius of the circle and the side of the square, except for the obvious fact side is $\ge 2a$. Presumably a sensible question is being asked. Maybe the centres of the circles are supposed to be collinear. If so, the radii are related. But the problem doesn't **say** the centres are collinear, and there is no drawn line that hints at it. Perhaps you could ask the original question, **exactly** as it was asked, with original picture, and in German.

Comment: die originalfrage: Man berechne die Längen der Radien r1,r2,r3 in Abhängikeit von der Seitenlänge a der drei gegebenen Quadrate. Please find the length of the radius r1,r2,r3 in dependence of the side length a of the three given squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top picture, it appears that all three circles are meant to be tangent to $AC$.  Also, you can see gaps in the other segments approximately where the segment $AC$ should be.  Perhaps there was a line here that did not reproduce.

Adding this to other information from the picture:

- $AA_1D_1D$, $A_1A_2D_2D_1$, and $A_2BCD_2$ are all squares with side length $a$.
- Circle $M_1$, with radius $r_1$, is tangent to $CD_2$, $D_2A_2$, and $AC$.
- Circle $M_2$, with radius $r_2$, is tangent to $A_1D_1$, $D_1D_2$, and $AC$.
- Circle $M_3$, with radius $r_3$, is tangent to $AD$, $DD_1$, and $AC$.

$M_3$ is then the incircle of $\triangle ACD$.  This triangle is right, with legs $AD=a$ and $CD=3a$, so it has hypotenuse $AC=\sqrt{10}a$, area $\frac 32 a^2$, and perimeter $(4+\sqrt{10})a$.  A triangle with area $K$ and perimeter $p$ has inradius $2K/p$ (this can be seen by dissecting the triangle into three triangles by drawing segments from the incenter to the vertices.)  In this case then the inradius of $\triangle ACD$ is
$$
r_3=\frac{2\cdot\frac 32 a^2}{(4+\sqrt{10})a}=\frac{4-\sqrt{10}}{2}a.
$$
Since $M_1$, $M_2$ and $M_3$ are all homothetic with center $C$ in the ratio $1:2:3$, $r_2=\frac23 r_3$ and $r_1=\frac 13 r_3$.

Comment: Thank you, you made my day :-)

Comment: just one short question, because I can´t find on google. qhats homothetic?

Comment: does is mean, that the cathetus are that size, 1:2:3? that would make sense to me. Thank you ;-)

Comment: It means that the circles can all be superimposed with each other by a transformation which leaves $C$ fixed and moves any other point $P$ along the line $PC$, shrinking or expanding the distance $PC$ by a fixed ratio.  In this case, it implies that the circles are in the ratio $1:2:3$, and that the right triangles circumscribed about them are similar in the same ratio, $1:2:3$.

Comment: oki thank you for help!